# Howto monitor traffic between IIS and MSSQL

Tags: networking, sql-server-2008, iis-7, firewall, tcpdump

I am trying to check how much traffic is flowing between MSSQL Server and IIS Server in different locations. There is 1 ipcop in every location and I download the tcpdump file from one firewall and search for `DST=ipmssql` and `SRC=ipIIS` but I did not find the IP from the database server, however there is traffic between both.

Any suggestions as to why I did not find the IP address from the MSSQL Server? Is this a configuration failure in IPCop or is the traffic between IIS and MSSQL so strange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to answer that without knowing exactly what you want to monitor and why: bandwidth use ? number of transactions ? Number of connections ? Debugging an application ? Security check ? All these can be done but requires different approaches.

Anyway, if I where you, I'd start by going to the DB server and checking the SQL performance counters to see if you don't have what you're looking for in there.

Comment: Hey Stephane, thx for your answer. I only want to monitor the bandwith usage for traffic between both Servers. Its for information only. 

I looked for a performance counter on SQL Server but i didn't find a counter like "SQL Server: Network performance" or something like this. It was the reason that i want to sum the tcpdump file but there are no traffic between this IPs. Can anyone explain an IIS <-> MSSQL Network Session?

Comment: By default, if using the TCP connector, MSSQL client and servers will talk over TCP port 1433. You should, however, check the exact connection string used to know how the data is exchanged. Remember also that this traffic could be encapsulated.

Answer (score 0):

You'll also want to understand that traffic doesn't flow between "IIS" and SQL Server. It will be flowing between one of the worker processes managed by IIS and SQL Server.  This means you'll want to find out whether the applications in question are ASP.NET, Classic ASP, or whatever, so you can discover the worker processes.